# Pin names are getting skewed in Altium Designer while printing

Tags: altium

My friend is trying to print a schematic that was created in Altium. Everything looks OK while viewing in Altium, but when I try to print it to PDF, the pin names and even port names are getting skewed. This is happening even when I use smart PDF to create the PDF.

[image: view in Altium]

It seems only things that have been rotated are affected by this.

[image: skewed image]

It used to work properly in the beginning, but after a few days it suddenly started to go wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about rendering a print in a pdf file and not about EE. The fact that the picture being rendered happens to be a schematic does not mean this is an EE problem.

Comment: You should state the version of Altium, since this might be a known bug. Also, you should better take this question to the formums on live.altium.com . People there are generally really helpful and have seen their share of AD bugs, so they might know the reason and a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Had exactly the same problem with Altium 16

Go to: DXP -> Preferences -> Schematic -> General
Uncheck the "Render Text with GDI+"

Fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

This issue still exists in versions going up to 20 or 21.
Looks like you're using a font different from what Altium is originally configured with. Altium's built-in "smart" PDF print utility is broken unless you use the font Altium expects.

I use a monospaced font (no ambiguities between 1, l, I, O, 0) which caused justification issues with PDFs (extra spaces added to labels). 
My solution is to use an external PDF printer utility.